# how do you use pygame.sprite.Sprite?

Tags: pygame, sprite

I am currently writing a small game under separate files and am having an issue with `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. Every time I go to run the player class I get this error `AttrbuteError: "module" object has no attribute "sprite"`. I have done many searches on this site and have also looked on the pygame website for answers but I have only found other bits of code and answers that do not resolve my  current issue. If anyone could help me with my issue that would be great.
here's my class for the player:

```
import pygame
import pygame.sprite as Sprite
class player(Sprite.sprite):
   def _init_(self,plyrmovement,plyrhealth,plyrdirection):
      Sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
      def plyrmovement(left,right):
          position=[100,100]
          direct_left = 'player left'
          direct_right = 'player right'
          def right():
              if event.key == ord('d'):
                  position[0] += 5
                  plyrdirection = direct_right
                  sprite.sprite='playerleft'
        def left():
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                position[0] -= 5
                plyrdirection = direct_left
                sprite.sprite = 'playerright'
        def shoot(self,bullet):
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                bullet.bulletmove
        def plyrhealth(self):
            self.health = 100


class bullet(pygame.Sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self,bulletmove,bulletdamage):
        pygame.image.load('bullet sprite.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full name is `pygame.sprite.Sprite`.

If you use `import pygame.sprite as Sprite` then correct name is `player(Sprite.Sprite)` not `player(Sprite.sprite)` - see upper `S` in both `Sprite`.

As for me it is better to use `class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` and `bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` - lower `s` in first `sprite` and upper `S` in second `Sprite` - and without `import pygame.sprite as Sprite`

```
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,plyrmovement, plyrhealth, plyrdirection):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    # ...rest...

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, bulletmove, bulletdamage):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    # ...rest...
```

---

BTW:

- it has to be two _ before and after `init`
- you could use CamelCase names for classes - Player, Bullet - similar to Sprite, Rect. See suggestions in PEP8 ([PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))(PEP8 - [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names))
- use empty line before `class` and `def` to make code more readable (PEP8 - [Blank Lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines)).

Comment: Thank you for responding I will try this and let you know if that fixes my issue.

Comment: just tried it and the bullet sprite was working fine before, it was only the player class that wasn't working. this is what I have when I run the program. on line 2, in <module> class player (pygame.sprite.Sprite): AttributeError : "module" object has no attribute "sprite".  this has been bugging me for the past month and I don't know what is causing it for just the player class or why it is only happening to the player class.

Comment: have you named any file `pygame.py` or sufolder `pygame` ? if you have file `pygame.py` then `import pygame` try to use your file instead of expected module.

Comment: I made sure not to name any file pygame, not even the screen is named pygame (which I have seen  other users do by mistake.) I guess I could just slap all the separate classes into one file.

Comment: so I ended up turning them into objects then changing them back to sprites with the default sprite code `pygame.sprite.Sprite`  and that ended up working to my surprise. I don't understand why the error ended up fixing itself like that but I hope that someone will see this and try what I did so that it doesn't bother them too.